# Generalized "Homology Whitehead" -- How much does stabilization remember?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy

Classically, the (non-local-coefficients) homology Whitehead theorem says that if $X \xrightarrow f Y$ is a map of simple spaces, and if the induced map $H_\ast(X;\mathbb Z) \to H_\ast(Y;\mathbb Z)$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ is a weak homotopy equivalence.

Conceptually for me, the essence of this theorem is that we have a *stable* invariant ($H_\ast(-;\mathbb Z)$), and we identify a (reasonably large) class of spaces (the simple spaces) such that our invariant detects equivalences when restricted to this class. I'm wondering how generally a statement of this form holds in a fairly general $\infty$-category $\mathcal C$ in place of $Spaces$.

For my purposes, I'm not particularly concerned with *which* stable invariant we use, so we might as well restrict attention to the universal case. Moreover, there are two general forms of "stabilization" which come to mind -- the category of spectrum objects $Sp(\mathcal C) = \varprojlim (\cdots \xrightarrow \Omega \mathcal C_\ast \xrightarrow \Omega \mathcal C_\ast)$, and the Spanier-Whitehead category $SW(\mathcal C) = \varinjlim (\mathcal C_\ast \xrightarrow \Sigma \mathcal C_\ast \xrightarrow \Sigma \cdots)$ (I use $\mathcal C_\ast$ to denote the $\infty$-category of pointed objects in $\mathcal C$). But we're eventually passing to some subcategory anyway, so we can reduce the $SW$ notion to the $Sp$ notion if we start out by replacing $\mathcal C$ with $Ind(\mathcal C)$ via the equation $Ind(SW(\mathcal C)) = Sp(Ind(\mathcal C))$.

Thus we are led to the following formulation:

> **Question:** Let $\mathcal C$ be a presentable $\infty$-category. Can we identify a (reasonably large) full subcategory $\mathcal D \subseteq \mathcal C$ such that the composite functor $\mathcal D \to \mathcal C \xrightarrow {\Sigma^\infty_+} Sp(\mathcal C)$ is conservative? In particular, is this the case for $\mathcal D$ being one of the following?
>
> - The 1-fold suspension objects?
> - The 1-fold loop objects?
> - The 1-connected objects?

Here, a *1-fold suspension object* is simply an object of the form $X = \Sigma Y$ for some $Y \in \mathcal C$; a *1-fold loop object* is an object of the form $X = \Omega Y$ where $Y \in \mathcal C_\ast$ is a pointed object of $\mathcal C$. A *1-truncated* morphism $W \to Z$ is a morphism such that for every $C \in \mathcal C$, the map $\mathcal C(C,W) \to \mathcal C(C,Z)$ has 1-truncated fibers, a morphism is *1-connected* if it is left orthgonal to the 1-truncated morphisms, and an object $X$ is *1-connected* if the map $X \to 1$ is 1-connected, where $1$ is the terminal object.

As a sanity check, I think each of my candidates for $\mathcal D$ are trivial when $\mathcal C$ has discrete hom-spaces, which is a good thing because in this case $Sp(\mathcal C)$ is also trivial.

Comment: Is it important to you that $\mathcal{C}$ be an arbitrary locally presentable $(\infty,1)$-category, or would it be sufficient to consider the case when it is an $(\infty,1)$-topos?  In the latter case, the result would follow from a proof of the homology Whitehead theorem in homotopy type theory; I don't know if that exists in the literature yet, but it's at least not too far off.

Comment: Taking $\mathcal{C}$ to be $n$-groupoids (aka $n$-truncated spaces), it seems to me that all of your criteria fail (because the stabilization is trivial).

Comment: @MikeShulman It would be nice to understand the $\infty$-topos case, although I am interested in going beyond this.

Comment: @LennartMeier That's a very good point. Offhand, I can't think of a natural restriction to put on $\mathcal C$ to rule this out, other than simply asking $\mathcal C$ to be an $\infty$-topos...

Comment: Another question is whether hypercompleteness will matter.  I looked back over my notes and I believe I know how to prove a "homology Whitehead theorem" in HoTT saying that if a map of 1-connected types induces an isomorphism on integral homology, or on cohomology with coefficients in all abelian groups, then the map is $\infty$-connected (i.e. induces an isomorphism on all homotopy groups).  If this works, then it would imply a positive answer in the case of $\infty$-toposes where $\mathcal{D}$ is the _hypercomplete_ 1-connected objects.  But I don't know how to do better right now.

Comment: The cohomology version of @MikeShulman's argument was written up by my student Luis Scoccola on pages 20 and 21 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03245 .  He cites Mike's blog post, where these ideas originated.

Answer (score 6):

Putting together my and Dan's comments deserves to be called an answer.  Namely:

If $\mathcal{C}$ is an $(\infty,1)$-topos, then the statement is true when $\mathcal{D}$ is the class of *hypercomplete, pointed, nilpotent* objects.  Hypercompleteness is the usual $(\infty,1)$-categorical notion, pointed is obvious, while "nilpotent" here means that the internal group object $\pi_1(X)$ is nilpotent and acts nilpotently on each internal abelian group object $\pi_n(X)$, in an appropriate internal sense.

For a proof, see section 3 of [Nilpotent Types and Fracture Squares in Homotopy Type Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03245) by Luis Scoccola, which proves in homotopy type theory that any cohomology isomorphism between pointed nilpotent types is $\infty$-connected — hence an equivalence if the types are hypercomplete.  Then we get the result for $(\infty,1)$-toposes by interpreting homotopy type theory internally therein, as shown [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07004) for universes and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07088) for higher inductive types.  (Those papers don't yet quite complete the interpretation by showing that the universe is closed under HITs, but I doubt that this proof depends crucially on that.)

Note that the assumption used here is weaker than yours, namely that an isomorphism is induced only on internal cohomology group objects with coefficients in all internal abelian group objects.  It seems likely that with your stronger assumption hypercompleteness could be removed from the result, but probably a different method would be required.